# Manual intervention required for booting - How do I automate this?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, uefi, aspire-one

I have Ubuntu 12.04 running exclusively on my aspire one 756 netbook, I downloaded the 64bit iso and made my install on a usb-stick.

**First issue:** it did not boot automatically from that stick, I had to choose the usb efi device manually to boot and install from.  However the installation went fine

Now the system won't boot normally and I always need to choose the efi part manually to boot.

The bios (updated yesterday to v1.09) and has no 'legacy boot' nor a 'secure boot' option to choose from. The grub update with "boot=efi" made no changes.

Is there a solution to automate this?

thanks in advance

update: i've run boot-repair over it. maybe it helps [boot-repair info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5567676/)

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v`. (If you get an error, type `sudo modprobe efivars` and try again.)

Comment: `BootCurrent: 0000
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Ubuntu HD(1,800,2f000,f5723659-d019-41f5-abbc-16ffa96ec60b)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series           BIOS(2,500,00)................-...........A..........................................
Boot0003* Ubuntu HD(1,800,2f000,f5723659-d019-41f5-abbc-16ffa96ec60b)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0004* ubuntu HD(1,800,2f000,f5723659-d019-41f5-abbc-16ffa96ec60b)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)`

Comment: hi @rod-smith, i hope this helps

Comment: @Machine Always edit your answer with new information, don't post it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

One part of the answer is from Acer saying 'if you are on BIOS 1.x, stay on 1.x'

A german Acer forum gave me the advice to do a low-level-format prior to installing the x64 version.
I have not tested this, as I'm back to 32bit (up and running smooth).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in Ubuntu:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0,3,4,1
```

If that doesn't work, then I have three other suggestions:

- Run the Ubuntu [Boot Repair tool.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) I'm not 100% positive that it will work in your case, but it might.
- Type `sudo mkdir -p /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT; sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. This will copy GRUB to a fallback/default EFI boot loader filename that might work.
- Download and install the Debian package version of my [rEFInd boot manager,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) then type `sudo mvrefind.sh /boot/efi/EFI/refind /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT`. This will put rEFInd in the fallback/default boot loader position. If *that* doesn't work, try typing `sudo mvrefind.sh /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot`. This last command copies rEFInd to the default location used by the Windows boot loader, which some *very* badly-written EFIs insist on using.

You can try these in any order you like, although I've listed them in increasing order of complexity.

Comment: hi @rod-smith, thanks so long for your help.
i tried part one, but it only works temporarily, back to same after reboot. i know try the next steps.
`~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
BootOrder: 0001,0000
~$ sudo efibootmgr -o 0,3,4,1
BootCurrent: 0000
BootOrder: 0000,0003,0004,0001
~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
BootOrder: 0000,0003,0004,0001
`

Comment: i slowly begin to think, thats it's not an ubuntu or even efi problem, but its my bios.
acer has two different bioses to download and one is the win8 type with efi and stuff.
unfortunately its officially not supported to do an update from the 1.x to the 2.x bios.
i've contacted acer for more information.

Comment: update:
run boot-repair. problem is the same but now i have an additional windows boot manager entry to start from.
[boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5572938/)

Comment: Technically, your computer has no BIOS; it has a UEFI (or an EFI 2.x). BIOS and (U)EFI are two different types of firmware. Manufacturers sometimes use the term "BIOS" in reference to their EFIs, which is incorrect and confusing. In any event, it sounds like you may have a buggy EFI. You can try my other suggestions, but I can't guarantee that they'll help. You might also try creating a new entry for the boot loader with a name (`-L` option to `efibootmgr`) of "Windows Boot Manager". See http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/20187.html for more on this.